# Can't select all links with a certain textContent after using querySelectorAll and a for loop

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

The purpose of the following code is to have a comfortable way to open all links with a certain `textContent`, in a new tab.

My HTML is very simple in this case:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="https://google.com">Edit</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://google.com">Edit</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://google.com">AAAA</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://google.com">AAAA</a></li>
</ul>
```

To target all a's with the `Edit` `textContent` I tried to use the following code that filed:

```
let links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    let link = links[i];
    if (link.textContent == 'Edit') {
        window.open(link.href, '_blank');
    }
}
```

What is wrong here? I just a have a collection, I iterate it, and in each iteration do a task if the condition is true.

Comment: Nothing is wrong here, but I suspect your browser had blocked the popup

Comment: @AngYC you ninja'd me. Credit goes to you :)

Comment: That's fine, but the first moment I saw this code was like: "Whoa, opening 4 tabs at once? Browser is going to be crazy" haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers have built in popup blockers to prevent a script like this to open up a bunch of windows. Back in the days the advertises would do that often which made surfing the web really hard.

There is no way I know of to open a bunch of new windows with js that is reliable across browsers unless the user clicked each link manually, sorry.